# Reverse Search in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to know if the Postgresql can handle the following usecase ?

We have an app that crawls adverts from different platforms. The users can add searches, with the  keyword and other filters attributes (price, location, etc). When we receive a new advert, we want to find all the searches that match to the advert details.

I need to check which one of these queries (searches) match with an Advert object each time when an Advert is received.

This is basically a reverse search.

**UPDATE**

Example:

I have this `searches table`:

`+----+-------------------+------------+----------+
| Id | keyword           | startPrice | endPrice |
+----+-------------------+------------+----------+
| 1  | iphone 8 plus     | 100        | 300      |
+----+-------------------+------------+----------+
| 2  | Ipohne 7          | 50         | 500      |
+----+-------------------+------------+----------+
| 3  | iphone 8          | 200        | 300      |
+----+-------------------+------------+----------+
| 4  | headphones iphone | 10         | 300      |
+----+-------------------+------------+----------+`

Now I have and `advert` object with the following structure:

`{
   title: Sell Iphone 8 plus 32GB, white,
   price: 250
}`

I want to make a query on `searches` table, to find all the searches that map to this advert. In my example I expect to return only the searches `1 and 3`, because the `250` price is between `startPrice` and `endPrice` and their `keyword` is in `advert.title`: Sell **Iphone** **8** **plus** 32GB, white

Even if the advert.title contains the `iphone` word, I don't want to receive the searches with ID `2 and 4`, because their `keywords` doesn't completely match (`advert.title` doesn't contain **7** and **headphones**)

Elasticsearch has [Percolate Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) which gives you the ability to store a query and run that query for every element in your collection.

Comment: In order to answer this we'd need to know how your data was structured. Can you show how your tables are structured and relate to each other? The answer is that it's almost certainly possible, but exactly how is going to depend very much on information we don't currently have.

Comment: @MichaelPowers I updated my question with an example. Let me know if it's ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to match all keywords in a particular string you can use the [PostgreSQL full text search feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-textsearch.html) like this:

```
SELECT id, keyword, startPrice, endPrice
FROM searches
WHERE
    startPrice <= 250
    AND endPrice >= 250
    AND to_tsvector('Sell Iphone 8 plus 32GB, white') @@ to_tsquery(array_to_string(string_to_array(keyword, ' '), ' & '));
```

Which results in the following:

```
 id |    keyword    | startprice | endprice 
----+---------------+------------+----------
  1 | iphone 8 plus |        100 |      300
  3 | iphone 8      |        200 |      300
```

This query will match any string that contains all keywords. Be careful to make sure keywords can't contain any characters containing matching symbols (e.g. !, &, |, etc).

Comment: You're solution works even for an advert with the title `Sell Iphone white, 8 plus, 32GB, white` ?.
`strpos` will give me the first position of the substrig and in this case I want to check if all the words from the keyword are found in the advert.title